# When doing a comparison tests between series, can you use any arbitrary starting point n to compare?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Say you have two series:

1) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$

2)  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$

can you compare the sequences from $n = 5$ and onwards, at which point $1/n^2 \gt 1/n!$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ is known to be converging therefore $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$ converges from $n = 5$. Is that a valid argument?

Comment: Just to comment that using the comparison test seems awkward here: the series 1) is easier to analyze (by the ratio test) than 2)... unless you recognize $p$-series by heart :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this is because the terms you ignored are *finitely* many, hence adding them up to the rest, doesn't change the finitess of the series.